# Launch sikulix server with SSH connection

Tags: python, ssh, sikuli

Some usefull information: the VM are on Azur and run Windows 10, my local comp also run Windows 10, I have OpenSSH_server installed on my VM, port 22 & 50001 are both open for inboud/outbound.

Here is my issue:

I have a program running a graphic interface on my local computer (compA), it allow me to connect to remote computer with SSH (using the fabric module for python), and to display output inside a text widget. I successfully connect to my VM (compB), and run via SSH a .cmd on compB. The .cmd file has one line: `java -jar C:\Redacted\sikulix\sikulix.jar -d 2 -s`

When executing it manually, it's working great, I have access to `http://localhost:50001/`, I can execute script.

When I execute it via SSH, all I see is the OpenJDK Platform binary process starting, but I can't access `http://localhost:50001/` and can't execute script.

I can execute other commands like `ipconfig`, `dir`.

Is there a reason that would prevent the sikuli server from starting via SSH ? Is there something I'm missing ?

Edit1:

Here is how I do the SSH connection (using fabric module)

```
client = fabric.Connection(host=hostname, user='redacted', connect_kwargs={'password': 'Redacted'})
```

and here how I run the command (fabric module)

```
command = "java -jar C:\\SaisigoWriter\\sikulix\\sikulix.jar -d 2 -s"
client.run(command)
```

I also have a redirector for output:

```
class TextReddirector(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
        self.widget = widget 
        self.tag = tag

    def writer(self, output_str):
        self.widget.config(state="normal")
        self.widget.insert("end", output_str, (self.tag,))
        self.widget.see(tk.END)
        self.widget.update()
        self.widget.config(state="disabled")

    def flush(self):
        print("")
```

Comment: Is the OpenSSH server running in anything resembling a desktop session, or is it maybe just a service without a desktop?

Comment: OpenSSH server is running on a windows 10 VM, it has a desktop session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find out that, by doing `echo` before trying to start the javacommand, everything work, amazing.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? I'm having a similar issue